# C++ getline error

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error and I can't figure it out:

> no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list
>       argument types are: (std::istream, MyEnum)

**Code**

```
enum MyEnum // Needs to be before the struct that uses it
{
    Dog, Cat, Fish, Squirrel
};
struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    float b;
    string c;
    MyEnum d;
};
int main()
{
    char myCString[arraySize] = { 0 };
    char myOtherCString[] = { "Yet another string" };
    int myInt[4] = { 27, 39, 0, 42 };
    string myString;
    MyStruct aStruct = { 4, 3.5, "Dogs", Dog };
    int x;
    int * pX = &x;
    array <MyStruct, arraySize> Animals;
    // Storing values in uninitialized variables
    myCString[0] = 'A';
    myString = "A third string";
    x = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        Animals[i].a = rand() % 10;
        Animals[i].b = rand() % 100 / 100.0;
        Animals[i].c = MyEnum(rand() % 4);
        cout << "Enter a name: ";
        getline(cin, Animals[i].d);
    }
```

Comment: `arraysize` is not defined. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you're 90% of the way there. Also missed some other lines off the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to get input in `Animals[i].c`, because `c` is the `string`, and `d` is not.

Also, you probably want to assign `MyEnum(rand() % 4);` to `Animals[i].d`

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    Animals[i].a = rand() % 10;
    Animals[i].b = rand() % 100 / 100.0;
    Animals[i].c = MyEnum(rand() % 4);
    //        ^^^
    // Change it to Animals[i].d
    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    getline(cin, Animals[i].d);
    //                     ^^^
    // Change it to Animals[i].c
}
```

It's just a bad naming style, you should have some meaningful names for variables, with some meaningful names, you'll probably never have this kind of errors.

Comment: +1 For correctly pointing out that, had OP not chosen such poor (read: terrible) names for types and variables, he/she never would've run into this problem.